# Not able to see output of state using react hooks (useState) after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am fairly new to react so i am sure i am missing something very simple or way off. I am trying to complete a simple axios api fetch and set the response to a state. I am able to see the data in console log but nothing seems to be happening when i try to set it to state. I have tried approaches useState, useEffect, useReducer with help from various blogs and i am not able to see the output so i am definitely not doing something right.

EDIT: I am trying to do this on load of the page, and not on click events.

I am able to get the counter examples available on the react (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to work w/o any issues. I am following a mix of examples from several blogs and not able to see the results.

https://www.andreasreiterer.at/rest-api-react-hooks/

Eventually i would like to incorporate the data from the api into the Material table ui

Any helpful insights would be really appreciated. I have been stuck on these for the past two days.

```
function LandingPage = () => {

    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("ent useeffect")
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const result = await axios(
            window.location.origin + "/api/MESampleData",
          );
          console.log("before if")
          if(result){console.log(result)}
          console.log("before setrows")
          setRows(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
      }, []);

return (
        <div className="section">
            {<h6>It should render</h6>}
            <ul>
                {rows.map(row => 
                    <li>{row.item1}</li>
                    )}
            </ul>
</div>)
}

export default LandingPage;
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW1hU.jpg)

Comment: What specifically is `result`?

Comment: Hello - result is the response from the Axios fetch and result.data is expected to be an array of records.

Comment: I'm asking what's actually there, not what's expected--e.g., show the result.

Comment: please see the sample output screenprint if that helps.

Comment: ahhh crap. i see what you mean now. I was not grabbing the right data element and putting it into the setRows object. I just saw the results array and thought that was it. Let me fix and deploy again.

Comment: thank you for helping me find the answer. It wasnt the code, it was me not looking at the data properly.

Comment:  Always check your assumptions--you can also do things like drop a `debugger` in the JS so you can play with the data in the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the fetchData function outside of the useEffect, but continue calling the function inside the useEffect.

Comment: i had tried that earlier and tried it again with no luck

Answer (score 0):

ahhh crap. i see what you mean now. I was not grabbing the right data element and putting it into the setRows object. I just saw the results array and thought that was it.